# Error on the Search Screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I am testing the http://careers.stackoverflow.com/?bmidr=1bbbb website

I have found a issue on the site with searching. When I have entered very long values in the *what* and *where* textboxes, you end up at a blank screen

See these screenshots:

**Search Page**

[image]

**Result Page**

[image]

I know the URL is very long, but you need to check for this and display *some* message to the users if they enter wrong values in the search textbox.

Comment: This is a specific example of the more general bug you described in the other post; solving that will solve this one.

Comment: Technically different code bases, different teams. I reopened the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should now see an error page when you access an URL which is very long.

Since we don't have a specific error message for this (very sparse) error, it will show a "Page not found" error.

Thank you for the report !

Comment: You forgot to remove the [meta-tag:status-reproduced] tag from the question. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, yes. Thanks!