# No error message if the URL is very long

Tags: bug, error-message

I entered a URL with a very long parameter on Stack Exchange.

I have type this url 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/?_=36470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555564564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564

It shows a blank screen , does not shown any messages.

[image]

We need to show a “Page Not Found” message, same as what you did on other Stack Exchange pages.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a real link somewhere that has this issue?

Comment: @Stijn , Sorry, I can't get you. What you mean?

Comment: What I'm asking is, did you try this purely to see if it would break, or is there a page somewhere that has a really long link that is broken by this bug?

Comment: I got tis  problem, When i add extra parameter values (like query string) in the URL

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat , It's very cheating, Where is the answer for my question on there? Why it's duplicate?

Comment: Because of how similar these two problems are, the right thing to do would probably have been editing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229821/error-on-the-search-screen to say that this happens on all pages that have a long URL.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: I'd make the *other* question a dupe of this one, since this one more clearly explains the problem.

Answer (score 6):

An overly long URL like that should probably be handled as a [400 Bad Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) or [415 Request-URI Too Long](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15).

You *do* get a 404 response:

```
$ curl -D - "http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?_=36470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555564564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555556364705104645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555555636470510464564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555555563647051046456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564564564564564555555555555555555555555564564565466456456456456456456456455555555555555555555555556456456546645645645645645645645645555555555555555555555555645645654664564564564"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 10:05:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

But a *400 Bad Request* or *415 Request-URI Too Long* response body wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes, But why it's shown blank? Why it's not go to page not found screen? We need to so a error message to user

Comment: *"But a 400 Bad Request response body wouldn't hurt."* He's agreeing with you @RameshRajendran.

Comment: @Bart , Yep. That is a bad request. but my question is Why the MSE and MSO does not show a message for that?

Comment: bugs feed developers, those are put in deliberately... :-)

Comment: @RameshRajendran: because bug, that's why.