# Comments are cleared under question when migrated

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, migration

**My one [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229828/no-error-message-if-the-url-is-very-long)  is migrated here  from meta.SO.**

Some peoples are commented under the question on met.So. But that comments are cleared when  migrated here  from meta.SO.

Why?

**My guess**

> - If the user did not register  here? So that comments are deleted.

**Is it correct?**

> But i can saw the comments under [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229829/259096) . I am little confused.

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Vogel612 , I can't see any answer for remove comments when  migrate a question

Comment: me neither. It's still the faq-post on the topic of migration, so I thought I'd link it here, that not everyone looking at this question has to search for it ;) Quoting the answer: " It **preserves** the current revision of the question, all its answers, and **any comments** on any of those posts, as well as most of the votes."

Answer (score 4):

Tim purged all the comments on that thread before he migrated the question here, probably because the majority of the comments were about how the question belonged here and not there, which doesn't make for a very useful comment thread on this site.

This was not something that the system does on its own - it was a moderator explicitly deleting all the comments before the migration took place.

Comment: There is one case of automatic deletion of comments during a migration. Comments that link to the destination site will be removed on the assumption that they're of the "you should ask this on $destinationSite" nature.